# Can I gather dataloader objects from processes using torch.distributed.all_gather_object?

Tags: python, pytorch, distributed-computing, pytorch-dataloader

I am new to distributed training on multiple GPUs. Following the tutorial in [here](https://yangkky.github.io/2019/07/08/distributed-pytorch-tutorial.html), I believe my model is the same on all GPUs, and the distributed sampler is creating dataloaders for each of the processes.
Assuming that this is correct, then each of my GPUs have access to a subset of my data, and I should have a separate `loader_train` for each rank.
Now mid training, after (lets say) epoch 10, I need to gather all the dataloader objects into a list. My solution is to use `all_gather_object`.

When I try the following code:

```
dloader_all = [None for _ in range(torch.distributed.get_world_size())]
torch.distributed.all_gather(dloader_all , loader_train[torch.distributed.get_rank()])
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'DataLoader' object is not subscriptable
```

I wrote the code following the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html). What am I missing here? How can I gather the objects into a list where `list[0]` is the dataloader from the first rank and so on?
I would appreciate any help.

Update:
My solution as of right now, is to gather the data from multiple gpus, and
(on rank zero) add it to the dataset, and then create a distributed sampler, and dataloader.

Update (solution):
I managed to fix this using the code and idea in [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-concatenate-different-size-tensors-from-distributed-processes/44819) and [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark/blob/main/maskrcnn_benchmark/utils/comm.py).
Basically, I serialized the dataset, converted it to bytestorage, padded it (since my data was not of the same size), gathered and then unpadded and unserialized it.